# Could not load file or assembly 'UnityEngine.Purchasing'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm getting this error while building the game.

> Could not load file or assembly 'UnityEngine.Purchasing,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies.

Screenshot of the console:

[image]

I'm new at Unity and trying to run existing source code.

Comment: I shared my case here. The same reason what I met and solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/74976079/713101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error is caused by UnityPurchasing and this is a bug that occurs sometimes.

**1**.Go to *Windows* --> *Services* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and it should open a tab.

**2**.Sign in on that tab.

**3**.Finally, enable the Unity services that you're using after signing in.

In your case, I see `UnityEngine.Purchasing.ProductCatalog` in the error log and this means that you're using the "In-App Purchasing" service. So, enable the "In-App Purchasing" service in the Service tab.

---

If you still have issues, do the following:

**1**.Go to the `<ProjectDirectory>/Assets/Plugins` path

**2**.Delete the UnityPurchasing folder. You may have many error but just ignore it.

**3**.Restart the Editor.

**4**.Open *Windows* --> *Services* then sign in again. Re-enable the services.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the JAVA_HOME variable to the JDK install folder 
If the problem still persist try installing Unity 5.4 version as this bug is not present in that version